# How to read data from file c++

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream, fstream

I have a `data.txt` file organizing as follows:

---

> nodeNum 
>  
>   10 
>  
>   NodeId   Coordinates 
>  
>   0  0    0 
>  
>   1   1   1
>  
>   2   2   2
>  
>   3   3   3
>  
>   4   4   4
>  
>   5   5   5
>  
>   6   6   6
>  
>   7   7   7
>  
>   8   8   8
>  
>   9   9   9
>  
>   Edge(from i to  j)  Weight
>   0   1   1.5
>  
>   1   1   2.1
>  
>   2   1   3.3
>  
>   3   1   4.0
>  
>   4   1   5.0
>  
>   5   1   6.6
>  
>   6   1   3.7
>  
>   7   1   8.1
>  
>   8   1   9.3
>  
>   9   1   10.2
>
> ---

How can I read and store the data in as follows:

```
int nodeNumber; // <--------- get and store number in line number 2 in text file.

std::vector<Node> nodes(nodeNumber);   
double x1, y1;

for (int i=0; i< nodeNumber; i++) {
    nodes.at(i) = g.addNode();
    x1 , y1 //<-- x1 and y1 store coordinate from line 4 to line 4 + nodeNum, respectively 
    coord[nodes.at(i)].x=x1;
    coord[nodes.at(i)].y=y1;
}
```

From the line:

> Edge(from i to  j)  Weight //(line number 3+nodeNum (=3+10) ) to the end.
>   
>   i <-- first number, j <-- second number, z[i,j] < --- 3th number.

I have no idea to do this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicates, ["stackoverflow c++ read from file"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+C%2B%2B+read+from+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: The issue is that the core of the question is duplicate, but the question in whole is slightly different than other questions posted here about reading integers from a file.

Comment: @dsz Why suggest `fopen` and `scanf` when we have streams in C++?

Comment: Ok, I get the fopen & scanf are old-school, and I've just realized the tags were looking for a streams solution. Should just have stuck with my last point.

Comment: @dsz _"I get the fopen & scanf are old-school, ..."_ No they aren't _old school_, these simply were never part of c++ school.

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how to read line number 2 store this number to int nodeNumber, then STOP. Then declare a vector of size nodeNumber which has been read before, and continue read number from line 4 to 14, store in ID, x[ID], y[ID]. From line 16 to last line: read i<- first number, j <- second number, z[i][j] last number. I look up on Internet alot but it doesn't help because I am not smart. Please help me !

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `class` or `struct` to represent a line of data from the file.  Next would be to overload `operator>>` to read in the data (and optionally removing the newline).

```
struct Coordinate
{
  int x, y, z;
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Coordinate& c);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Coordinate& c)
{
  input >> x >> y >> z;
  return input;
}
```

You input loop for a vector of coordinates becomes:

```
std::vector<Coordinate> points;
Coordinate c;
while (data_file >> c)
{
  points.push_back(c);
}
```

The input will fail when reading something that is not a coordinate.  At this point, clear the stream state and read the edge records.

Comment: Could it be modified to read the file line by line and extract only the numerical values?

Comment: Yes.  Look up `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`.  So, instead of the using `data_file`, you would use the `std::istringstream`.  C++ is nice this way, since `istringstream` is derived from `istream`, no changes to the `Coordinate` class are required.

Comment: But this only help to deal with one separate path. How can I skip the line 1, 3, 14. How can I read line number 2 and store in int nodeNumber and STOP, then declare a vector of size nodeNumber?

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how to read line number 2 store this number to int nodeNumber, then STOP. Then declare a vector of size nodeNumber which has been read before, and continue read number from line 4 to 14, store in ID, x[ID], y[ID]. From line 16 to last line: read i<- first number, j <- second number, z[i][j] last number. I look up on Internet alot but it doesn't help because I am not smart. Please help me !